# Web3.py Transaction Keeps Timing Out

Tags: transactions, web3.py, infura, receipts, goerli

I'm attempting to send a transaction using web3.py between an address I created & my metamask account on goerli. Everything seems to go well until confirming the transaction, at which point w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt() always times out, and upon checking the balances of the addresses, the transaction never goes through.

The following is my code.

```
from web3 import Web3
#Import for ethereum account creation, does not require node connection
from eth_account import Account

#Necessary middleware to connect to goerli
from web3.middleware import geth_poa_middleware

#Necessary to sign transaction
from eth_account.messages import encode_defunct

#Intialize metamask address
metamask_address = "0xAfADBc095D871d58ee2D170CC52443C51169F06e"

#Infura goerli
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("https://goerli.infura.io/v3/{api key}"))

# inject the poa compatibility middleware to the innermost layer
w3.middleware_onion.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0)
print(w3.isConnected())

#Verify no accounts available
accounts = w3.eth.accounts
#Create account, after creating save key & address
"""
acct = Account.create('{entropy}')
acct_address = acct.address
print(acct.address, acct.key)
"""
acct_address = '0x74f04fBC4d7DA3b38CF94de15C2B6ee7cA0BFe62'
acct_key = b'{private key}'


#Get Balance after sending geth from metamask
acct_balance = w3.eth.get_balance(acct_address)
print(acct_balance)
print('w3 gas price', w3.eth.gas_price)

#Create transaction of 0.01 geth back to metamask account
transaction = {
  'from': acct_address,
  'to': metamask_address,
  'value': 10000000000000000,
  'gas': 100000,
  'gasPrice': w3.eth.gas_price,
  'nonce': 15
}

#Sign Transaction
signed_transaction = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(transaction, private_key=acct_key)
#print('dir of signed_transaction', dir(signed_transaction))
#Send Transaction
transaction_hash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_transaction.rawTransaction)
print('txn hash', transaction_hash)

transaction_receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(transaction_hash)

#Check Balance again of both 
print(w3.eth.get_balance(acct_address))
print(w3.eth.get_balance(metamask_address))
#print('txn hash', transaction_hash)
```

The error I keep running into is

```
web3.exceptions.TimeExhausted: Transaction HexBytes('0x4466eb5190201f1f699867abaa31442da2258d05c8d23ca1f45b2af286b236d1') is not in the chain after 120 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use for transfers, I just tested it and it works on Goerli.

> I already put your addresses in "sender" and "receiver", just missing the private key that you can place as you like!

```py
from web3 import Web3

node_url = "GOERLI_ENDPOINT"  # Goerli endpoint URL
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(node_url))  # establish connection to a node

# verify the connection is successful (will return true)
if web3.isConnected():
    print("Connection Succsessful")
else:
    print("Connection Failed")

# set the adresses
# build transactions
# sign

sender = "0x74f04fBC4d7DA3b38CF94de15C2B6ee7cA0BFe62"
receiver = "0xAfADBc095D871d58ee2D170CC52443C51169F06e"
private_key = "YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY"

# nonce
nonce = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(sender)

# build the transaction
tx = {
    "nonce": nonce,
    "to": receiver,
    "value": web3.toWei(0.01, "ether"),
    "gas": 20000000,
    "gasPrice": web3.toWei(10, "gwei"),
    "chainId": web3.eth.chain_id,
}

# sign tx
signed_tx = web3.eth.account.signTransaction(tx, private_key)

# send transaction
tx_hash = web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
print("Transaction hash:", web3.toHex(tx_hash))
```

It could also be something to do with the endpoint you are using. I use [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com/) (which is free) and it worked great.

Follow these steps to sign up on Chainstack, deploy a node, and find your endpoint credentials:

1. [Sign up with Chainstack](https://console.chainstack.com/user/account/create).
2. [Deploy a node](https://docs.chainstack.com/platform/join-a-public-network).
3. [View node access and credentials](https://docs.chainstack.com/platform/view-node-access-and-credentials).

They also have a page in the docs with a lot of [JSON-RPC API call examples](https://docs.chainstack.com/api/node-api-reference), and the code actually works!